Issue resolving registry.quarkus.io/maven for Nexus repo update
we are currently trying to upgrade from Quarkus 3.10.0 to 3.12.0
after installing the latest quarkus-cli (3.12.0) and running
quarkus update
we are getting the following errors (using a corporate Nexus repo)
[WARNING] Failed to resolve the Quarkus extension registry descriptor of registry.quarkus.io from shp.mirror (https://[OUR_NEXUS_REPO].com/repository/SHP-Public/) having applied the mirrors and/or proxies from the Maven settings to registry.quarkus.io (https://registry.quarkus.io/maven). Re-trying with the original registry.quarkus.io repository configuration.

then
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.12.0:update (default-cli) on project [OUR_PROJECT]: Failed to initialize Quarkus extension resolver: Failed to resolve the Quarkus extension registry descriptor of registry.quarkus.io from registry.quarkus.io (https://registry.quarkus.io/maven) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.12.0:update (default-cli) on project [OUR_PROJECT]: Failed to initialize Quarkus extension resolver

my understanding in this area is rather patchy, so please bear with me.
Using
mvn io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.12.0:update -N
I get more or less the same error
I contacted our Nexus server admin with the information from this page
https://quarkus.io/guides/extension-registry-user
=> "How to register as a Nexus Repository proxy"
so that he could add registry.quarkus.io to our Nexus repo
But he doesn't really see how this can work as the Maven url
https://registry.quarkus.io/maven
returns an HTTP 404
Is this url correct? If so how is it suppose to work in the Nexus config?
Thanks
